# Separate custom settings variable between development, staging and production

Tags: django

I'm following the project structure [as laid out by Zachary Voase](http://blog.zacharyvoase.com/2010/02/03/django-project-conventions/), but I'm struggling with one specific issue.

I'd very much like to have a custom settings boolean variable (let's call it SEND_LIVE_MAIL) that I would be using in the project. Basically, I'd like to use this settings variable in my code and if SEND_LIVE_MAIL is True actually send out a mail, whereas when it is set to False just print its contents out to the console. The latter would apply to the dev environment and when running unittests.

What would be a good way of implementing this? Currently, depending on the environment, the django server uses dev, staging or prd settings, but for custom settings variables I believe these need to be imported 'literally'. In other words, I'd be using in my views something like

```
from settings.development import SEND_LIVE_MAIL
```

which of course isn't what I want. I'd like to be able to do something like:

```
from settings import SEND_LIVE_MAIL
```

and depending on the environment, the correct value is assigned to the SEND_LIVE_MAIL variable.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't be importing directly from your settings files anyways. Use:

```
>>> from django.conf import settings
>>> settings.SEND_LIVE_MAIL
True
```

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution is to have this at the bottom of your settings file:

```
try:
    from local_settings import *
except ImportError:
    pass
```

And in local_settings.py specify all your environment-specific overrides. I generally don't commit this file to version control.

There are more advanced ways of doing it, where you end up with a default settings file and a per-environment override.

This article by David Cramer covers the various approaches, including both of the ones I've mentioned: http://justcramer.com/2011/01/13/settings-in-django/

Comment: The method the OP is using is actually pretty awesome. I've been using it myself for awhile. It nets you the ability to commit all your settings (production, staging, even multiple individual developer settings) all to your repository, and then you only have to create symbolic link to which specific settings file you want to use. It's pretty slick.

Answer (score 2):

```
import os
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.dirname(__file__)
try:
    execfile(os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, local_settings.py'))
except IOError:
    pass
```

Then you can have your `local_settings.py` behave as if it was pasted directly into your `settings.py`:

```
$ cat local_settings.py
INSTALLED_APPS += ['foo']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this for a wide variety of environment based settings, but here's an example for just `SEND_LIVE_MAIL`.

**settings_config.py**

```
import re
import socket

class Config:
    def __init__(self):
        fqdn = socket.getfqdn()
        env = re.search(r'(devhost|stagehost|prodhost)', fqdn)
        env = env and env.group(1)
        env = env or 'devhost'
        if env == 'devhost':
            self.SEND_LIVE_MAIL = # whatever
        elif env == 'stagehost':
            self.SEND_LIVE_MAIL = # whatever
        elif env == 'prodhost':
            self.SEND_LIVE_MAIL = # whatever

config = Config()
```

**settings.py**

```
from settings_config import config

SEND_LIVE_MAIL = config.SEND_LIVE_MAIL
```

Comment: That would be an alternate to his current way of implementing settings. It doesn't really provide a solution to his problem as his project is currently configured. Even then, though, it's not a good idea to import settings from the actual settings.py file. Django exposes the actual settings be used at `django.conf.settings` so there's no reason to do anything special.